# Mailto links in iOS not working

Tags: ios, iphone, mailto

Whenever I try to add a simple mailto link, all devices except iOS work fine.

Based on [Apple iPhone Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MailLinks/MailLinks.html) it should work as such:

```
<a href="mailto:frank@wwdcdemo.example.com">John Frank</a>
```

But I made a new post on a WordPress site that contains the URL exactly as such and when tapping it on iPhone (iPhone 7 simulator and real iPhone 6) it just gives an error:

[image]

Comment: I tried this page and it works: https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_mailto

Then I tried editing the link, removing the "target" attribute, and on my iPhone 7 the link stopped working. Then I did a 3D Touch on the link and I saw a dialog stating the website wasn't allowed to open links and was given the opportunity to cancel or allow.

Comment: @ryan have you resolved it?

Answer (score 19):

Use a real device, not the simulator. Mail and phone apps are not installed on the simulator, so you can't use them.

From [Mail Links](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MailLinks/MailLinks.html) in the [Apple URL Scheme Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html):

> **iOS Note:** If the Mail app is not installed, clicking a mailto URL displays an appropriate warning message to the user.

Comment: "an appropriate warning message"
It shows nothing at all. I even have the mail app installed.

Answer (score -4):

You can adding onclick event and get it done:-

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.location='frank@wwdcdemo.example.com'; return false;" class="noHighlight">John Frank</a>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: That just triggers a redirect to the url `frank@wwdcdemo.example.com`